Possibilities for even quadratic
Is the only possibility for an even quadratic $ax^2$ + b where a and b are constants? Also is it necessary for the coefficients to be real?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It is not necessary for the coefficients to be real, as the example $x^2+i=(-x)^2+i$ shows

Thank you for your reply! Please confirm the first part as well.

If the coefficient of $x$ is $c$, and the quadratic is even, then $$a(-1)^2 + c(-1) + b = a\cdot 1^2 + c\cdot1 + b$$.
